# python livereload does not output unittest test output correctly

Tags: python, python-unittest

Trying to run my unittest program forever using python livereload. The output of the test is coming in the wrong format; it is difficult to quickly read and understand it. The below screenshot shows the program and output:

[image]

How to solve this output problem?